# Query in ManyToMany relation

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have two models with ManyToMany relation. 
Here is the code:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('m', 'Male'),
    )
    tournaments = models.ManyToManyField('Tournament', through = "PlayerTournament",verbose_name = u"Tournament's players")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, verbose_name = u"First name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = u"Last name")
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = SEX_CHOICES, default = 'f', verbose_name = u"Sex")
    elo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = u"ELO")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['elo']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.last_name, self.first_name)

class Tournament(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = u"Tournament's title")
    players = models.ManyToManyField('Player', through = "PlayerTournament",verbose_name = u"Tournament's players")
    beginning_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = u"Tournament's beginning", null=True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PlayerTournament(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Player)

    class Meta:
        db_table ='game_player_tournaments'
        auto_created = Player
```

I'm trying to make a query to fetch related fields

```
PlayerTournament.objects.filter(tournament__title = "Winter").values()
```

But it doesn't work

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title' into field. Choices are: elo, first, first_name, id, last_name, playertournament, second, sex, statistics, tournament, tournaments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your models:

```
class PlayerTournament(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

You have `player` and `tournament` interchanged

You should be doing:

```
PlayerTournament.objects.filter(player__title = "Winter").values()
```

and if you are *indeed* looking for related fields, you should be using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) instead of [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) (Which I highly doubt based on your quqery)